# Stuck Streaming Xml

Tags: asp.net, xml

This is the code i have written to get the xml of one url but it says
"Data at the root level is invalid" with any url.. Can someone specify why?

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();//xml doc used for xml parsing                           
xdoc.LoadXml("http://latestpackagingnews.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default");//loading XML in xml doc
XmlNodeList xNodelst = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("entry");//reading node so that we can traverse thorugh the XML
Response.Write(xNodelst);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`XmlDocument.LoadXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx) method awaits XML-text, but not the source URL.

First, download page content into `string` and then pass it to `LoadXml`. Here is how you can download:

```
public string GetUrlContent(string url)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
    var content = reader.ReadToEnd();

    reader.Close();
    response.Close();

    return content;
}
```

In your case it would be:

```
var content = GetUrlContent("http://latestpackagingnews.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default");
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `xdoc.LoadXml` can not for read url, change it to `xdoc.Load` and it will work.

You can also read : [Using Returned XML with C#](http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/howto-xml_cs.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first download your xml data using WebClient class

```
string downloadedString;
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
downloadedString = client.DownloadString("http://latestpackagingnews.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default");
//Now write this string as an xml
//I think you can easily do it with XmlDocument class and then read it
```